# Using jquery to randomly show something

Tags: jquery, animation, random

My problem is this:

I have `div` with a background image, the opacity is `0`! When you hover over it the opacity becomes `1`, but I also want it to randomly show it some times. So I'm kind of looking for a way to randomly give this `div` the opacity value `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(someFunction, 1000);  //1000 is milliseconds to next random check
});

function someFunction(){
    var chance = 10;  //1 in 10 chance to show the div
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*chance)+1;  //generate random number 1-chance
    if(rand == 1) //show the number
    {
        $('#someId').css('opacity', 1);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#someId').css('opacity', 0);
    }
}
```

You can adjust the times and chance to determine how frequently the id is shown.

Comment: This looks really promising, but could you please check i think there is some syntax error... thank you!

Comment: Changed this to actually work, and to modify opacity instead of using jQuery hide.

Answer (score 1):

something like :

```
var d = new Date();
if (d.getTime() % 3 ==0) 

opacity = 1
else 0;
```

Comment: Date is a constantly changing variable.  1/3 of the time this code is called (% 3), it will be true.

Comment: this is ticks ! its a huge number which you have 1/3 chance of true. its like saying : " select a big number for me and see if it %3"

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's

```
<script>
  var sets = {
  minsec: 1,
  maxsec: 10
  };

  var t=setTimeout("showthediv()", (Math.floor(Math.random()*(sets.maxsec - sets.minsec)) + sets.minsec)*1000);

  function showthediv()
  {
      if ($('#element').queue().length == 0)
      {
          $('#element').fadeTo('slow',1);
      }
      var x=setTimeout("showthediv()",(Math.floor(Math.random()*(sets.maxsec - sets.minsec)) + sets.minsec)*1000);
  }
</script>
```

**Edit:** made it configurable for timeframe as well as added a check to see if animation has finished. Settings are in seconds instead of miliseconds

Comment: You probably need to at least wait until the previous fade is done before setting your next random setTimeout.  You could end up with multiple fades try to go at once.

Comment: You want to use setInterval for this.  The code you have could potentially throw a "too much recursion" warning.

Comment: Toast could you please tell me how would i do that... sorry but im a begginer

Comment: I had forgot a closing ). The OP asked for a random timeframe, and this is a truly random timeframe, ill add a line to make it check if the animation is already finished